# Angular Error: transition superseded at $StateProvider.$get

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, dependencies

Recently I have updated my angular dependency, but i didn't update ui router dependency, because version 1.0.0 is not working. So  now I am using angular version 1.7.0 and ui router version 0.3.2 and I am getting below error on my console :

```
Error: transition superseded
    at $StateProvider.$get (external_dependencies.js:7718)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5093)
    at angular.js:4882
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:5036)
    at external_dependencies.js:8513
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5093)
    at angular.js:4892
    at q (angular.js:374)
    at fb (angular.js:4892)
    at c (angular.js:1923)
```

However I tried to update ui version to 0.4.1,0.4.2 and 0.4.3 but its not working for me. I also tried to hide with below code:

```
$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false)
```

But I am not sure it is a proper solution.

I also try with timeout:

```
 $timeout(function(){
   $state.go('statename')
})
```

but it is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think your question should be about this "_because version 1.0.0 is not working_". what's your original code and why it doesn't work?

Comment: No, my concern is why it is not working with 0.3.2

Comment: I've had the same issue recently, I was forced to work with the same versions of angular and ui-router as you mentioned and the fix was exactly the same thing that you did. I really don't know what is the issue here with that version specifically, but what I can tell you is that my application is working in production with that fix for months, without any issues.

Comment: Which fix first one or second one

Comment: Sorry Kumar, I was referring to the $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false)  quickfix. As you stated the $timeout isn't working.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if it is a resolution or we are just hiding

Comment: As I pointed out, my production site is working without any issues. I believe there is some internal issue with that version of ui-router-angular combination that they weren't unable to fix. My advice to you is to not overthink it. Just take it as it is. If you are going to spend time working on resolving this issue, go for it. I would like to have a proper fix implemented as well.

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour of $q.reject changed. Read more here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246

Comment: I went through with this link but its not helping